# JavaScript: that vs this

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying to understand better the use of that and this in JavaScript. I am following Douglas Crockford's tutorial here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html
but I am confused regarding a couple of things. I have given an example below, and I would like to know if I am making a correct use of them:

```
function ObjectC()
{
   //...
}

function ObjectA(givenB)
{
   ObjectC.call(this); //is the use of this correct here or do we need that?

   var aa = givenB;
   var that = this;

   function myA ()
   {
      that.getA(); //is the use of that correct or do we need this?
   }

   this.getA = function() //is the use of this correct?
   {
       console.log("ObjectA");
   };


}

 function ObjectB()
 {

    var that = this;

    var bb = new ObjectA(that); //is the use of that correct or do we need this?

    this.getB = function()
    {
        return bb;
    };

    that.getB(); //is the use of that correct or do we need this?


 }
```

Note this is just an example.

Comment: Simple: `that` is not a keyword, but an ordinary variable name.

Comment: Before voting to close the question, please explain what you don't like about it so I have a chance to improve in the future.

Comment: "that" is just a variable used to store the current value of "this", which changes as the execution context of your program changes - ie when you enter a new scope

Comment: `that` is used to save the value of `this` because `this` of getB function is not the same than ObjectB

Comment: `this` is a keyword, `that` is just some variable name (it could be `sausages`).  In ObjectB you attempt to pass `that` to ObjectA before you have defined `that`.  In all of your examples, you could eliminate the use of `that` entirely and use `this`.  The only reason to use `that` is if your usage will be in a scope where `this` points to something else.

Comment: @James - my mistake, fixed it

Comment: http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ObjectC.call(this); //is the use of this correct here or do we need that?
> ```

The first thing you need to understand is [how the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) works. It's value depends on how the function/method/constructor is called.

In this case, `function ObjectA` is a constructor, so you can just use `this` inside the code of it. In fact, with `var that = this;` you declare them to be absolutely identical (unless you use `that` before assigning to it).

> ```
> function myA() {
>     that.getA(); //is the use of that correct or do we need this?
> }
> ```

Again, it depends on how the function is called - which you unfortunately have not show us. If if was a method of the instance, `this` would have been fine; but but it seems you will need to use `that`.

> ```
> this.getA = function() //is the use of this correct?
> ```

As stated above, using `that` would not make any difference.

> ```
> var bb = new ObjectA(that) //is the use of that correct or do we need this?
> var that = this;
> ```

`that` is `undefined` when it is used here. And it would be supposed to have the same value as `this` anyway. Better use `this`.

> ```
> that.getB(); //is the use of that correct or do we need this?
> ```

Again, both have the same effect. But since you don't *need* `that`, you should just use `this`.

Answer (score 24):

`this` in JavaScript always refers to **current object, method of which was called**. But sometimes you need to access `this` of your object in deeper. For example, in callbacks. Like so:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.a = 10;
    this.do = function() {
        http.get('blablabla', function(data) {
            this.a = data.new_a;
        });
    };
}
```

It will not work, because `this` in callback may refer to `http`, to some dom element or **just window**(which is really common). So, it is common solution to define `self` or `that`, an alias for `this` or your object, so you can refer it anywhere inside.

```
function MyClass() {
    var self = this;
    this.a = 10;
    this.do = function() {
        http.get('blablabla', function(data) {
            self.a = data.new_a;
        });
    };
}
```

**This should give you vision** *why* it is used and *how* it should be used.

**There is no other reasons**(*currect me if I'm wrong*) to create special variable, you can use `this` to send your object to other objects and *do things, many assignments, such logic, wow...*

Answer (score 3):

Everything is correct except for :

```
function ObjectB()
 {
    var bb = new ObjectA(that) //this is wrong
    var that = this;

    this.getB = function()
    {
        return bb;
    };

    that.getB();
 }
```

You are missing `;` and `that` isn't declare.

---

You need `that` (in your case, this is the variable name you use) when you want to use this in another scope :

```
function ObjectB()
     {
        var that = this;

        // here 'this' is good
        function()
        {
            // Here 'this' doesn't refer to the 'this' you use in function ObjectB()
            // It's not the same scope

            // You'll need to use 'that' (any variable from the ObjectB function that refers to 'this')
        };

        // Here 'that' = 'this', so there is no difference in using one or another
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

What "that" is in this context is simply a variable that is equal to "this". That means saying "that" is exactly the same as saying "this", which makes in unnecessarily complicating.

This code:

```
var that=this;
that.getA();
```

Will yield the same result as this code:

```
this.getA();
```

Having a variable to represent "this" just complicates things when you can just say "this".

Comment: -1 missing the point. This is sometimes necessary to reference functions of a classes' own object. Read other answers. It's not unnecessary.