# Losing value of "this" inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the hang of when "this" loses scope. I've read the doc on MDN and my understanding is that when an arrow function is used, it will keep "this" set as before the function was called. I can't figure out why my "this" is set right before returning a promise, but once inside the promise, "this" loses it's value and becomes undefined. Please see a code snippet below and check the comments for the value of "this". What do I need to change here to maintain the value of this within my promise?

```
async createMyFile(fileName, authorization) {
        // this has it's value correctly set here
        let clientUrl = this._getUrl(null, authorization);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // as soon as I enter the promise, this becomes undefined
            let testThis = this._myVal;

            // rest of code removed since it's not relevant
        });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24634723/5869805 "that" -pun intended- should help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: That arrow function should preserve binding, so if it isn't we'll need to see an example we can run where it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your use of an arrow function as your executor function. Arrow Functions don't have their bindings to a this variable and is generally problematic to use them in places where using `this` is required. You should use an anonymous function like this.

```
...
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            // as soon as I enter the promise, this becomes undefined
            let testThis = this._myVal;

            // rest of code removed since it's not relevant
        });
...
```

Take a look at [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more on the limitations of  arrow functions